# How do I see the contents of a Plastic Cloud repository without syncing it?

Tags: plasticscm

I have a 4 gig plastic repository that I'd like to delete. Is there a way I can see what's in the repository without having to download all 4 gigs? Like the "Depot View" in Perforce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

- From the Plastic "Branch explorer" view --> right-click the desired branch/changeset --> "Browse repository on this changeset".
- This way, you are able to navigate into the project tree and even download files if necessary (avoiding to perform a full workspace update).
- You may also find useful the Plastic SCM Drive feature: http://blog.plasticscm.com/2015/02/plasticdrive-dynamic-readonly.html

Answer (score 0):

You are able to access repositories from the WebUI that PlasticSCM made recently.

```
https://www.plasticscm.com/orgs/[YOUR ORG NAME]/repos
```

Read more about it here:
https://blog.plasticscm.com/2021/07/announcing-webui-v2.html